# Laravel Eloquent builder - combining groupBy and orderBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application, and I have a query that is supposed to function as follows. The aim is to get the best selling item by the total quantity_purchased.

```
item item_id   date      quantity_purchased
rice | 14  | 2019-03-23 | 3
chicken | 6 | 2019-03-23 | 2
chicken | 6| 2019-03-20 | 3
corn | 2 | 2019-02-10 | 1
rice | 14 | 2019-03-04 | 5
rice | 14 | 2017-02-10 | 2
```

The aim is to get the best selling item by the quantity_purchased.  It needs to group item by the item_id, then sum the quantity_purchased for that item and order the grouped Items by the total quantity_purchased. In the example above, this should return

```
item   total_quantity_purchased
rice | 10
chicken | 5
corn | 1
```

I have tried to accomplish this using the eloquent query below:

```
    return self::where('isRefundedCompletely', false)
     ->get()
     ->groupBy('item_id')->orderBy(function($item) {return $item->sum('qty_purchased');}, 'DESC');
```

but i got this error:

> `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.`

Can you explain to me how to effectively resolve this issue, with a different approach, but without resorting to a raw query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just put this here. For reference purposes.

```
return self::select(DB::raw('item,sum(quantity_purchased) as total_quantity_purchase'))
        ->where('isRefundedCompletely',false)
        ->groupBy('item_id')
        ->orderBy('quantity_purchase','DESC')
        ->get();
```